# Electron architecture API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, go, electron

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I'm currently diving in into cross-platform apps with Electron.
As I'm a newbie to this topic there are some uncertainties:
In "normal" webdevelopment I would write an API in Go(lang) which processes JSON files. 
Is it possible to set up Electron like an offline server which can make API calls?

Thank you in advance. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Electron is Node.js+Chromium. I'd suggest to start with "normal web development" and explore Node.js before dealing with same things in Electron.

Comment: @estus Thanks for your reply. But I'd like to make a program together with a friend and he has front-end skills and I have got some backend skills in writing APIs and but as it has to process personal data it needs to be a desktop application because of GDPR.
I wanted to know if it is possible to develop a Electron app API driven.

Comment: You can use Electron as both a server and a client, but it seems a bit strange. Could you elaborate on what is your goal?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to make it API driven. You essentially need to learn how to do this with Node. Normally you would set up a server (e.g. Express) to serve requests to front end part, e.g. via HTTP. In Electron, but you have additional option to pass data to front end directly via IPC. Both options are acceptable, the latter is more straightforward in Electron but cannot be easily translated to/from regular website/server architecture in case it's needed.

Comment: I think @estus gave me the hint to elaborate my question:
Is it possible to make http requests to an offline API in Electron?

Comment: Depends on what 'offline' exactly is. Do you refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events ?

Comment: @estus No. I'm referring to the fact that the app runs locally on the machine as I'm unwilling to deal with the GDPR.

Comment: Yes. In case you're communicating between frontend and backend via HTTP, there is localhost webserver that listens only to frontend requests. In case you're communicating via IPC there will be no such problem.

Comment: Ok then what does IPC mean?

Comment: Inter-process communication. There are two different processes, main (powered by Node.js) and renderer (powered by Chromium). See https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md and https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md . That's one of few things that are specific to Electron. In other cases you can learn how to do the job with Node.js and extrapolate the experience to Electron.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and and here is a library [go-astilectron](https://github.com/asticode/go-astilectron) that demonstrates this approach. You can read more in the article [How to add a GUI to your Golang app in 5 easy steps (powered by Electron)](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-add-a-gui-to-your-golang-app-in-5-easy-steps-c25c99d4d8e0). It's based on this project [astilectron](https://github.com/asticode/astilectron) - Electron app that provides an API over a TCP socket that allows executing Electron's method as well as capturing Electron's events.